# Transposing rows to columns (with limitations on what methods I can use)

Tags: ruby, transpose

I'm doing a practice problem and the question is to transpose rows to columns in Ruby.

I understand `while` loops are "rookie-esque" in Ruby, but I think they prefer I use basic methods and control flow statements: `while`, `each`, `map`. Obviously, I can't use `Array#transpose`. They want me to basically  write `Array#transpose` from scratch.

It keeps telling me:

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my code:

```
def transpose(rows)
  idx1 = 0
  cols = []

  while idx1 < rows.count
    idx2 = 0
    while idx2 < rows[idx1].count
      cols[idx1][idx2] = rows[idx2][idx1]
      idx2 += 1
    end
    idx1 += 1
  end

  return cols
end

puts transpose(rows = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]
])
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your outer `while` loop you need to make `cols[idx1]` an empty array, else it is `nil` in your inner `while` loop:

```
while idx1 < rows.count
  cols[idx1] = []
  idx2 = 0
  while idx2 < rows[idx1].count
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. Would you recommend a better way to do this, using the same methods? Or do you think the way I did it was fine?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help you:

```
def transpose(rows)
  idx1 = 0           # => 0
  cols = []          # => []

  while idx1 < rows.count                  # => true
    idx2 = 0                               # => 0
    while idx2 < rows[idx1].count          # => true
      cols[idx1][idx2] = rows[idx2][idx1]  # ~> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
      idx2 += 1
    end
    idx1 += 1
  end

  return cols
end

puts transpose(rows = [
  [0, 1, 2],             # => [0, 1, 2]
  [3, 4, 5],             # => [3, 4, 5]
  [6, 7, 8]              # => [6, 7, 8]
])

# ~> NoMethodError
# ~> undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

That was created using "Seeing Is Believing" in Sublime Text 2.

Breaking it down, here's where you're going wrong:

```
cols = []   # => []
cols[0]     # => nil
cols[0][0]  # ~> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

You can't use a sub-index on a nil. The first index doesn't exist in the empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using [Array#new](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) with a block:

```
Array.new(rows.size) { |i| Array.new(rows.size) { |j| rows[j][i] } } 
  #=> [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

Alternatively, you could use methods from the class [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html), for which you need:

```
require 'matrix'
```

Here's an easy way that does not use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose), though it may not satisfy the spirit of the question:

```
Matrix[*rows].transpose.to_a
  #=> [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

However, you could do this:

```
Matrix.build(rows.size) { |i,j| rows[j][i] }.to_a
  #=> [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this for comparison using nested `Enumerable#map`s:

```
rows = [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]

def my_transpose(matrix)
  matrix.first.size.times.map { |column| matrix.map { |row| row[column] } }
end

my_transpose(rows)
# => [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]

my_transpose(my_transpose(rows))
# => [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```